# redirecting standard output, event is not raised

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

I'm trying to start a programm and read it's standard output. However the event is never raised.
The process i start is running and in console with the same arguments it creates output.
Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong?

```
    public void StartProcess(string Filename, string Arguments)
    {
        currentProcess = new Process();
        currentProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Programm;
        currentProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
        currentProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        currentProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        currentProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        currentProcess.OutputDataReceived += OutputReceivedEvent;
        currentProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        string path = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + "_Result.txt";
        LastResult = path;
        resultfile = File.CreateText(path);

        currentProcess.Start();
        currentProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        response.command = Command.ACK;
        SendMessage(response);

    }
    private void OutputReceivedEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        resultfile.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
```

EDIT: I just discoverd something odd: The process I start is mcast. If I start something else like ping, my code works just fine. So mcast seems to do something funny!

EDIT2: So the code below is working, but only reads blocks of a certain sizes, if less bytes are written to the stream, the even does not occur, neither does .ReadBlock return anything.

EDIT3: So one more update, the problem is, that mcast does not flush it's output stream. I ended up writing my own tool, which is working just fine.

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: U should call the functions? or am i thinking to easy?
`StartProcess(Filename,Arguments)`

Comment: Depending on the process you're launching, you might only receive StandardErrorOutput. Try registering your event to currentProcess.ErrorDataReceived as well.

Comment: @bash.d: debugger says: everything fine, there just never happens an event.

sander: what do you mean? I do call process.start() which uses the StartInfo I provide

June: good idea, but did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the process you may also need to use `currentProcess.ErrorDataReceived` and then `currentProcess.BeginErrorReadLine()` too, as some processes just redirect to one output, and not both. It's worth trying anyway.

So it would look like this:

```
public void StartProcess(string Filename, string Arguments)
{
    currentProcess = new Process();
    currentProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Programm;
    currentProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
    currentProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    currentProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    currentProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    currentProcess.OutputDataReceived += OutputReceivedEvent;
    currentProcess.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorReceivedEvent; 

    currentProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    string path = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + "_Result.txt";
    LastResult = path;
    resultfile = File.CreateText(path);

    currentProcess.Start();
    currentProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    currentProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    response.command = Command.ACK;
    SendMessage(response);

}
private void OutputReceivedEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    resultfile.WriteLine(e.Data);
}

/*This second event handler is to prevent a lock occuring from reading two separate streams. 
Not always an issue, but good to protect yourself either way. */
private void ErrorReceivedEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    resultfile.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```