# Sending CTRL+C to a process without killing my window

Tags: c#, process, cmd

I have a console application, that spawns a "cmd mcast /recv... > somefile.txt"

(process.standardoutputstream does not work properly with mcast, if you want to contribute to this issue see [redirecting standard output, event is not raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874251/redirecting-standard-output-event-is-not-raised/15909396?noredirect=1#15909396) )

I need to send a ctrl+c to mcast and use this code:

```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   static extern bool GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(
   uint dwCtrlEvent,
   uint dwProcessGroupId);

    void start(string path)
    {
        currentProcess = new Process();
        currentProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe";
        currentProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + "mcast /recv /grps:239.255.0.1 /dump:3"
                    + " > " + path;
        currentProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        currentProcess.Start();
     }

     void Stop()
     {
        Process mcast = Process.GetProcessesByName("mcast")[0];
        GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(0 /*CTRL_C_EVENT*/, (uint)mcast.SessionId);
      }
```

however mcast is sharing the console with my programm and mcasts sessionid is zero. so my program receives a CTRL+C too and terminates (which is really not what I want to do), any ideas?

EDIT: All my research suggests, that it is not possible to send a CTRL+C event to another process. Only WIN_CLOSE events can be send, which are ignored by console processes

Comment: Can you use `Process.Kill()`?

Comment: no I need to end mcast gracefully or I lose data

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling `currentProcess.CloseMainWindow()`, this should close cmd.exe, and cmd would, hopefully, close executing application properly.

Comment: CloseMainWindow is totally ignored by and cmd.exe and by mcast.exe, but thanks for the idea